# Async Queues In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, laravel-5, queue

I'm trying to implement Queuing, but the result is not async 
And I have Applied the following

```
config/queue.php
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),
    'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
   ]
```

and then applied the following commands
    php artisan queue:table
    php artisan migrate

and then run

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

and here is the functionality

```
SomethingController.php
   $model1 = new \App\Model1;
public function store(){
     Log::debug('before dispatch');
     $this->dispatch(new SendGiftCommand($model1));
     Log::debug('before dispatch');
     return true;
}



SendGiftCommand.php
{
    Log::debug('handle');
    SendGift::SendGiftAgedBased($this->model1);
    sleep(4);
    Log::debug('SendGiftCommand end');
}
SendGift.php
public static function SendGiftAgedBased(Model1 $model1){
  Log::debug('inside SendGiftAgedBased');
}
```

even the process has worked but its not async, and it waits for the command to finish to return the response in the controller

And I git the Logs in this order

```
 [2015-12-09 16:28:42] local.DEBUG: before dispatch  
 [2015-12-09 16:28:42] local.DEBUG: handle  
 [2015-12-09 16:28:42] local.DEBUG: inside SendGiftAgedBased   
 [2015-12-09 16:28:46] local.DEBUG: SendGiftCommand end  
 [2015-12-09 16:28:46] local.DEBUG: after dispatch
```

should it be working on Localhost  ?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with jobs not being asynchronous and this worked for me :

1. Edit **.env** and change the **QUEUE_DRIVER** setting from **sync** to **database** (editing **config/queue.php** wasn't enough)
2. Restart your processes

Comment: This helped me immensely -- no idea why this isn't in the documentation

Comment: Also, remember to run php artisan config:clear afterward

Comment: Is this database driver really asynchronous? I tried running it but doesn't look like it's running async operations. Every job is sequential and not in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the **job** to be queued, the job class needs to implement **Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue** interface - make sure it's true for your class.

You can find more info on queuing jobs here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes

Comment: It already implemented ShouldQueue , but should it act async on localhost ?

Comment: How do you know it's run synchronously? You have the queue:listen running so it might still be handled asynchronously but you're getting logs in correct order because it might be handled why your code is doing sleep(). Stop queue:listen process, dispatch the job without it running and see if the job gets executed.

Comment: thank you for help , I mean for me it seems to be sync,  but I want it to be async ,, how to achieve that ?

Comment: When you stop "queue:listen" - does the job get handled?

Comment: yes , it works , but when the queue:listen works or not , its sync. while I want it to work async , I'm using the localhost , is that affect the use of queuing ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to create the job:

```
   php artisan make:job SendGiftCommand --queued
```

Refer this link for defining the job:

```
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes
```

Then pass declare the job and dispatch the job in this manner:

```
    $processGift = new sendGiftCommand($model1);
    $this->dispatch($processGift);
```

Also refer Supervisor Configuration on the above mentioned link further for continuously listening to the queue or automatically restarting the command queue:listen if they fail.